# Extract timings from text string in Excel

Tags: excel, time, extract

I have been provided with a lot of timings from a Unix process, they appear in the format below;

system001: real 9m31.14s

system002: real 4m31.14s

system007: real 18m2.14s

system104: real 40m31.80s

These appear as a single column of data, with each system being on a unique row in an Excel worksheet.

I would like to be able to extract the minute and second values into a time based field so that I can calculate average runtimes, total runtimes etc.

What's the best way of achieving this given that I have thousands of rows of data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value is in column A, you could use these two formulae:

```
Minutes: =LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) -4- SEARCH("real ",A1)),SEARCH("m",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) -4- SEARCH("real ",A1)))-1)
Seconds: =MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) -4- SEARCH("real ",A1)),SEARCH("m",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) -4- SEARCH("real ",A1)))+1, LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) -4- SEARCH("real ",A1))) -SEARCH("m", RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) -4- SEARCH("real ",A1)))-1)
```

OR the way I did was to take the common formula out into column B to reduce repetition with formula: `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) -4- SEARCH("real ",A1))`
and then simplify the other two to use this (and allow Excel to reuse the last calculation instead of doing it over and over):

```
Minutes: =LEFT(B1,SEARCH("m",B1)-1)
Seconds: =MID(B1,SEARCH("m",B1)+1, LEN(B1) -SEARCH("m", B1)-1)
```

Of course you can still optimise this even more to calculate the index of 'm' just once and reuse that, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**text to columns**

Alternatively you can use `text to columns` option to repeatedly split text in the column

- split based on colon
- split based on space
- split based on m
- split based on s

Here is macro to do it automatically !

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=False, OtherChar:=":"
    Columns("B:B").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True
    Columns("B:B").Delete
    Columns("C:C").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, OtherChar:="m"
    Columns("D:D").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, OtherChar:="s"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't go past Line 2. Besides are you sure that's the right macro? Shouldn't your destination be ending up a column next to one you are processing like Column("A:A") -> Destination:=Range("B1")? Still a point to keep in mind for OP is macros security. Some places (like my previous office) wouldn't let you run macros. On the other hand, this method may be a little faster than formula method. I'd +1 you if I could get this code to actually run on OP's data

Comment: It also didn't work for me until I added "Tab:=False" to the 1st line of code.  But then I removed that argument and it ran fine the 2nd time.  Maybe you need to specify it for Tab, Semicolon, Space and Comma to ensure it works.